# How to read file in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

Edit: I had just forgotten a % in this line:

```
for /f "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (%cd%\JournalEntries\%filename4%.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
```

but now I run into a new problem. When it runs, the loop doesnt display the 
file's contents but instead just the letters j and k, assumedly from the point after the @echo %i.
Output: J K

```
:read2
echo All files are created in a MM-DD-YYYY format, meaning all files are read the same way.
echo Once the file opens, it will give you 30 seconds to read before resetting back to the next question.
timeout 5
set /p filename4= "What is the date of the file you would like to open (mm-dd-yyyy)?
for /f "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (%cd%\JournalEntries\%filename4%.txt) do @echo %i %j %k

timeout 30
```

Comment: It doesn't close, when you start it from an open command prompt. Then you surely see an error message about a syntax error (`for /?` tells you to use `%i` on command line, but `%%i` in a batch file)

Comment: wow, i didnt even notice, thanks! Though ive run into a new problem now. Ill edit the post to display new issue

Comment: you did remember to apply the syntax to all variables `%%i`, `%%j`, `%%k`, did you?

Comment: alright well it is fixed, thanks

Comment: Use `%%i` rather than `%i` so your code should look like this: `for /f "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %%i in (%cd%\JournalEntries\%filename4%.txt) do @echo %%i %%j %%k`

Comment: Consider reading the help file for the command you are using before you ask a question. The eighth line of the help clearly defines the problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you lacking a double quote in this part:

```
set /p filename4= "What is the date of the file you would like to open (mm-dd-yyyy)?
```

Comment: I see that, my bad, but the minor change didnt make any differences